# How to calculate these particular values in this experiment?

Tags: probability, statistics, experimental-mathematics

I am running a statistics experiment where I need to calculate certain values. However, this is where I am having difficulty.  Here is how the experiment works:

- Two Individuals Participate
- There is a spinner with 6 labeled tiles[1-6] and a regular die
- A player spins the spinner, and throws the die
- If the value obtained from adding the sums of the die's value and number on the spinner is 8 or greater, than the individual gets $10, otherwise nothing
- The first individual to get $80 in total wins

## Calculations

From what I have obtained so far, this is all I know:

$$P(obtaining $10) = 5/11$$
Number of trials to get 80 dollars[using geometric distribution] = $$(5/11)(1-(5/11))^7 = 0.006530$$

However, this just gives me a number between 0 and 1 - how can I turn this into the number of trials needed to obtain $80?

I'm trying to create a probability distribution along with find the the expected value and standard deviation - however, I need some assistance on where to start.

Comment: Should the probability be $\frac {5} {12}$ instead (assuming the outcome is equally likely and they are independent)? The way you compute the number should be the probability that getting the 10 dollar once in a specific sequence of $8$ trials. The number of trials needed to get 10 dollars $8$ times is following a negative Binomial distribution for a specific person. The number of trials needed for either one to win the game is the minimum of two i.i.d. Negative Binomial random variable.

Comment: @BGM Thanks for the response! It is 5/11 because the minimum value you can acquire from adding both minimum values is '2', thus it only ranges from numbers 2~11, 5 of which is 8 or greater. Also, do you think you could expand a little on how to perform the calculations for the last part of your comment? I grasp it a little but I'm still having difficulty understanding these things.

Comment: The distribution of the sum of two i.i.d. discrete uniform is no longer a discrete uniform. It will looks like a triangle. So you cannot simply say $\frac {5} {11}$. The number $\frac {5} {12} = \frac {15} {36}$ actually come from a sum. For the next part, please try to make clearer what you want to calculate. I suggest you have a look in wiki about negative binomial first.